# Facebook SDK Logout Function Issue

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using the Facebook PHP SDK in combination with the JS SDK on my site. Basically, the JS API logs the user in, and then the PHP part fetches all the user's info to display on the page.

The `logging` in part works fine: The user clicks on a button, that brings up the dialog FB dialog box. The `logout` function works on an onClick event too, except it doesn't really work, kind of. It does log the user out successfully, but when it redirects back to the homepage, an exception is thrown:

> "Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out".

When the page is refreshed, the error disappears. Could this be due to the logout function not properly deleting the session?

Here's the function I use to logout the user:

```
function FBLogout(){
   event.preventDefault();
   FB.logout(function(response){
      window.location.href = 'http://www.mydomain.com/';
   });
}
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook must be throwing this error as a response to an API call.

After you logout the user successfully, then a call has been sent to the facebook that is failed and this error was returned.

**Edit:**

Logging out from the JS-SDK wont invalidate the access token generated by the PHP SDK.

So do this-

- In the callback of `FB.logout`, call `$facebook->destroySession()`- you can do this by making an ajax call to a page with this call, and then on callback the user will be logout form both JS, and PHP

Comment: I have a try and catch block in the header. The error was thrown by an exception I made.

Comment: So that's fine. The user is logged out so the exception will be thrown, but what's the issue- seems fine to me

Comment: No, it's not. There's an if statement checking whether the user is logged in, before the try/catch block. The exception shouldn't have been thrown in the first place.

Comment: Lol, thats why you must share your code, you must be talking of `if($user)`.

Comment: Yea, sorry I'm new here. That's the check I'm doing, yeah.